# Using a type obtained through reflection in a data structure?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class `FutureClass` that exists in .NET 4.6, but I'd like to be able to use it in an older codebase that builds with .NET 4.0.  I can obtain and call `FutureClass` objects, but I want to store them in, say, a `Dictionary<string, FutureClass>`.

I've tried the following:

```
Dictionary<string, FutureClass> dict = new Dictionary<string, FutureClass>(); // didn't expect it to work
```

and

```
Type futureClassType = [...] //dynamically load the type from the assembly compiled with .NET 4.6
Dictionary<string, futureClassType> dict = new Dictionary<string, futureClassType>(); // held some promise, I thought
```

Is there a way to do what I'm trying?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as static typing your dictionary variable, I think you're limited to one of two options -- either use a `Dictionary<string, object>` or a `Dictionary<string, dynamic>`.

Otherwise, you could do something like this:

```
Type futureClassType = ...;
var dictionaryType = typeof(Dictionary<,>).MakeGenericType(typeof(string), futureClassType);
var dictionary = Activator.CreateInstance(dictionaryType);
```

But here, the resulting `dictionary` variable is of type object. You could cast it to a non-generic `IDictionary`, `ICollection` or `IEnumerable`, but you can't cast it to a generic form of any of the above.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the type at runtime has some severe handicaps like the one you just encountered. You cannot use the type in compile-time expressions like using it as a generic type parameter.

Your only option will be to copy the class over to your own codebase, which should not be too difficult because the .NET framework is officially open source now. The only trouble you might run in to is that the class has many .NET >= 4.5 dependencies, possibly recursively.

Comment: `FutureClass` has many intimate .NET 4.6 dependencies (new crypto libraries), so porting isn't an option

Comment: @Benjin well that sucks. Maybe you could convince your superiors to migrate the project to the newer framework? After all, that's in the best interest of both the company you work for and its customers. If the migration is hard now, it's only going to get harder. It won't get easier in any case, and .NET 4.0 is rather old now - support ends in january.

Comment: They say it'll be a 6+ month process to move everything over.  Didn't know support ends in Jan; maybe that'll light a fire under their ass.

Comment: A 6 month process to move from 4.0 to 4.6? Either they have no idea what they're doing, or the codebase is a gigantic mess. Such upgrade is mostly backwards compatible.

Comment: A combination of gigantic mess, scaring higher-ups with a large quote to put it off as long as possible, and leaving a sizeable buffer for things going wrong.